# Transfering MS Office templates from 2003 to 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

How can I transfer my templates from MS Office 2003 Pro running on Win XP Pro to MS Office Pro to MS Office Pro 2010 running on Win 7 Ultimate?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to copy the templates to the new PC and use them without changes.

1. Locate the template files on the Windows XP computer. These are in **C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates** unless you have set a custom template location.
2. Copy the template files to the Windows 7 computer. Place them in the folder **C:\Users\ user name \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates**

You may want to convert the templates from the 2003 format to 2010 format. This will allow you to use new features in the templates.

1. Open the template in Word, Excel, or PowerPoint.
2. Select Save As
3. Change the Save As Type to Word Template, Excel Template, or PowerPoint Template.
4. Click the Save button

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924460) has more information about managing templates.